# How to avoid the IF ELSE statements

Tags: c++, esp32

I have the following code, which does not look very nice. What methods could I use to make it look better?
Imagine that there are a lot of IF ELSE statements. As an example, I would like to distinguish whether the left is smaller or larger than the right. And more distances are added.
(It's about a robot that is supposed to detect obstacles in front of it.)

```
distance1 = left_LOX.distance();
distance2 = middle_LOX.distance();
distance3 = right_LOX.distance();

if (distance1 < 100 || distance2 < 100 || distance3 < 100)
  distance_case = 1;
else if (distance1 < 300 || distance2 < 300 || distance3 < 300)
  distance_case = 2;
else
  distance_case = 3;

// Abfragen für die Automatik
switch (distance_case)
{
case 1:
  target = 0;
  robot.Stop();
  delay(2000);
  break;
case 2:
  target = 4000;
  robot.Forward();
  break;
case 3:
  target = 6000;
  robot.Forward();
  break;
}
```

An idea on how to make it better would be nice.

Comment: C or C++? Pick one

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Doesn't look like C to me.

Comment: what is "nice" or "better" or  what you consider as "look better" is purely subjective. I think the code looks ok

Comment: For 3 variables this is perfectly fine. For more, I'd consider an array and [`std::any_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of)

Comment: And for many I would consider keeping distances sorted (or possibly binned into distance ranges) so it's easier to quickly determine if any are within certain ranges.

Comment: Doesn't eliminate much of the "ugly" code, but removes if-else if that's what you want:
```distance_case=(distance1<300 || distance2<300 || distance3<300) ? ((distance1<100 || distance2<100 || distance3<100) ? 1 : 2) : 3```

Comment: @Alexsen: the if-else are still there in the form of `?` and `:`, and this code is less readable. So what did you win ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Syntax of nesting if-else was removed. Even I mentioned the ugliness wasn't removed. It's just compressed if-else.

Comment: @Alexsen: no, the syntax of nesting is still there, via parenthesing.

Comment: @Alexsen  That can be simplified (since C++11) with an additional variable to `mindist = std::min({distance1, distance2, distance3}); distance_case = mindist < 300? ((mindist < 100) ? 1 : 2) : 3;`

Comment: @YvesDaoust might be a personal preference, but I far prefer  `? x : y` syntax over if-else pyramids.

Comment: @Peter That's actually  far better thing to do, would even consider an answer if you wanna write that down.

Comment: Im sorry for the missundastanding of my tags. Its an esp32. And the esp32 supports C and C++ right?

Comment: Here, it is the switch which seems redundant. `std::min({distance1, distance2, distance3})` might be stored in variable to simplify the conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a lot of distances (hundreds, thousand), it's easier to group all the distances together in a container such as vector first, and then use standard algorithms.  E.g. something like this:
This is assuming you have the C++ std library available on the esp32 platform/compiler you are using - it should be possible at least up to C++11 - see e.g. https://medium.com/geekculture/modern-c-with-esp32-dcd3918dd978.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    // Just an example vector initialisation - replace this with the required x_Lox.distance() calls.
    std::vector<int> distances = {300, 500, 500, 200, 100 };
    const auto min = *std::min_element(distances.begin(), distances.end());
    
    std::cout << "Min distance: " << min;

    return 0;
}
```

Once you have the minimum distance, you can run through the various cases for handling.  This is based on the assumption that you are only interested in the shortest distance to choose your robot's action.  If you have more complex logic, the code also gets more complex.

Comment: You are dereferencing `std::min`, is that a typo?

Comment: @FabiosaysReinstateMonica yes it was, thanks! - I meant to use std::min_element obviously, because comparing iterators for size is fairly useless ;-)

Comment: This looks good. Do you know if the esp32 is able to handle vectors?

Comment: If you have more complex logic, the code also gets more complex. Unfortunately I have to do this.

Comment: @Teebow To assist with logic that's more complicated than based around the current minimal distance, we'd have to see examples of this logic.  There's no "generic" answer, e.g. some of it might be based into putting distances into buckets - how many distances are closer than 300, how many further than 600, etc...
Looks like the esp32 programming environment should allow access to modern C++.

Comment: @JorisTimmermans okay I see. Unfortunately, I can't give an example of the more complex instructions yet. But your answer has already helped me a lot I think. I will take a closer look at it.

Comment: @Teebow - the std::algorithm library may have a lot of interesting stuff for you to do with a container of distances.  Or even a container of objects that include the distances and other things you need for your logic.  There's min and max, predicate finding, filtering, transforming...

Comment: @Teebow if you think this or any other answer has solved your issue sufficiently, could you please accept one?

Comment: @JorisTimmermans Sorry, I forgot about that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `if ... else if ... else` block directly if the `distance_case` does not have long term use. It unnecessarily introduces new variables which has no purpose. Or define an `enum` if you see, in long term, there will many such cases. Reader can also quickly make sense of the values.

Comment: It is rathera  comment not the answer

Comment: So you decided to abuse the system, because you do not enough reputation. Simply write more real answers and gain reputation. This restriction is for a reason. **never** use answers as comments here. I

Answer (score -1):

You can add if it looks better for you.

```
distance_case = (distance1 < 100 || distance2 < 100 || distance3 < 100) + 
                (distance1 < 300 || distance2 < 300 || distance3 < 300) + 
                (distance1 >= 300 || distance2 >= 300 || distance3 >= 300);
```

Comment: You can even omit the first part and use `1+(>=100)+(>=300)`